# Problem generating template using application - Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, console-application, executable

I am trying to generate a report with a table containing some data and a chart. When compiling using Netbeans, the program is completely compiled, but when I want to run using the application, only a graph is generated (for this I use jfreechar). I have tried to change the code several times, but every attempt to read and write the docx file is not carried out. When you try to create a new docx file and save it, everything works fine.

Below is the code I want to use to open and save the template.

```
void openSave() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Template.DOCX"));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("plik.docx");
    doc.write(fos);
    fos.close();  
}
```

Comment: Not really clear what your problem is. Your code only createes a `XWPFDocument` from `Template.DOCX` and writes this into `plik.docx`. After that both the files `Template.DOCX` and `plik.docx` should have identically content. At least for me this is the case using `apache poi 4.1.0`. Are your file contents different after that? If so how exactly? And how is `Template.DOCX` created?

Comment: Yes, this code should only copy contains of Template.DOCX ant than save that to plik.docx. When I'm using Netbeans this code works fine  but when I want to use application I don't receive any error but I don' receive the plik.docx too. I checked all code and only this part of code is not working corectly. Anwser for Your question is: "Are your file contents different after that?" - I don't recive the file, " If so how exactly?" - None, "And how is Template.DOCX created?" - Template.DOCX I prepared before and it contains some tables.

Comment: What does "when I want to use application" mean? Wild guess: You know that `new FileInputStream("Template.DOCX")` needs the file `Template.DOCX` placed in same directory, the JVM was started from? Same for `new FileOutputStream("plik.docx")` which places the file `plik.docx` in same directory. Such code is mainly used in examples. Productive code should have fully qualified file paths there.

Comment: I got it. Many thanks, the problem was not providing the path to the file directory, I thought that the template saved in the project folder would be enough. Application mean Executable Jar File

Comment: What I do not understand is why `new FileInputStream("Template.DOCX")` then not had thrown `FileNotFoundException`. If that code line had worked, then your result  `plik.docx` file would must be in same directory. As said, this  is the directory from which the `JVM` was started using the `java` command.